# 1040-ES Late Payment

Tags: united-states, estimated-taxes, form-1040x

quick question: I'm new to paying estimated taxes and I somehow forgot to file my last estimated taxes by Jan 15th this year - the payment due was for Sept-Dec 2018. I just realized this, and I want to pay it immediately to avoid accruing more penalties. I went to the IRS Direct Pay website and cannot select 2018 for 1040-ES filing/payment, only 2019.

My current plan is to mail the 4th Voucher for 2018 1040-ES with a check for the full amount I owe but I would definitely prefer to pay online. Can I submit the payment under 2019 online?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difficult time understanding 1040-ES and Late Payments Penalties](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84372/difficult-time-understanding-1040-es-and-late-payments-penalties)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the payment with the 2018 Q4 1040-ES voucher. Do not make an online payment for 2019; it definitely will not be applied to 2018.

I don’t know whether there is still a way to force an online estimated tax payment to be for 2018. Hopefully someone else can say.

A better option may be to file for an extension and make the payment with that. You can do this with Direct Pay. See the instructions for Form 4868. You can file your return at any time after filing for the extension.